# using 'rm -rf' safely

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I'm fairly new to unix and I have seen a lot of warnings against using `rm -rf`. 
Example: "But, always double check before you use `rm -rf` command, if you by mistake give this command in your home directory, or any other important directory, it will not ask to confirm, but it will delete everything there."

Can one still run this command followed by a directory name (`rm -rf dirName`) without deleting other important things if it is run from a home directory?

Generally, what are the safety rules while working with this command? What should one never type and where?

Comment: have you searched on google?  this is a very common question

Comment: Stop using `rm` and use [trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash-cli) instead. Put an alias in your .bashrc so you don't forget: `alias rm='echo rm is disabled, use trash instead'`

Answer (score 1):

`rm` will only delete what you tell it, so in that sense, it's always safe to use.  It will never randomly delete files on its own.

The danger is that it's easy to make a small typing mistake that ends up telling `rm` to delete a lot more than you intended.

As an example, imagine that you have a bunch of text files that you want to remove.  Of course you can type `rm *.txt` to remove them.  But what if you're distracted, or your finger slips on the keyboard, and you type `rm * txt` by mistake?  You just removed every single file in the directory.

For this reason, I have `rm` aliased to `rm -i`, so it prompts me for each file I remove.

Comment: I once had `rm` aliased to `rm -i` for my personal account. After `su` to root i did `rm *` hoping to confirm the deletes. The alias was not available for root, and I had serious problems. On the long run this alias can cause problems and IMHO it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This command is not dangerous, but it does exactly what it’s told, which is to delete things. The safest way to use `rm` is to not give it unnecessary flags.

If you need to delete a file:

```
rm file
```

If you need to delete a directory:

```
rm -r directory
```

You should only add `-f` if you don’t care about the permissions on the file or directory. In that case, `rm` will not prompt you if it can delete a file that you do not have write access on.

You can also add the `-i` or `-I` flags to make `rm` ask you more often if you really want to delete the files you passed to it.

Comment: This command absolutely is dangerous. It does what its meant to do and is a common command,  but it still can cause data loss - sometimes unrecoverable - and can have wider then intended scope if path referencing is not fully understood.

Comment: @davidgo That’s a valid opinion, but I believe globing is the dangerous part. The command just does what it’s told.

Comment: @Anonymous Just because the command does as it is supposed to, doesn't make it less dangerous.

Comment: @anonymous agreed. The scope of rm without to -r or -f is fairly limited. I was commenting on your opening statement "This command is not dangerous" which replies to the question about "rm -rf"